# cannot open pipe too many open files

Tags: awk

I am getting error,

fatal: cannot open pipe (Too many open files)

```
#!/bin/bash
output="Out.txt"
trans="DEBIT_TRANSACTION_"
ls *.txt | while read line
do
 subName="$(cut -d'.' -f1 <<<"$line")"

awk -F"|" -v var="10|" 'NF!=15;  NF==15 && /^[^[:space:]]/{ "echo -n "$6" | tail -c 3" | getline terminalCountry;
    if($6 =="") terminalCountry="IND";
  $1=var$1;$6=$6"|"terminalCountry; print $0;
}' OFS="|" "$line" > /home/lradmin/script/cboiCC/cboicTxnScrip/OUTPUT/"$subName$output"

done
```

Comment: Please do mention what is the value of `$line` variable in your post and let us know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 check my edits. Its the filename

Comment: `ls *.txt | while read line` is a well-known anti-pattern. Use `for line in *.txt` instead.

Comment: What exactly is `subName="$(cut -d'.' -f1 <<<"$line")"` supposed to be doing? I would expect the value of `$line` to be a filename, subject to the usual caveats of parsing `ls`... You're parsing the filename to eliminate extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are not closing your command which you pipe to your `getline`. You write:

```
"echo -n "$6" | tail -c 3" | getline terminalCountry
```

Awk does the following with this:

If the same file name or the same shell command is used with getline more than once during the execution of an awk program, the file is opened (or the command is executed) the first time only. At that time, the first record of input is read from that file or command. The next time the same file or command is used with `getline`, another record is read from it, and so on.

This implies if you have various `$6` which are identical, your command will work only correctly the first time. Furthermore, it will have opened a "file" where the command writes its output too. If you have many many records, it will continuously open files and never close them leading to the error.

For a correct working order, you should close the "file" again. That is to say, you should write:

```
command="echo -n \047" $6 "\047 | tail -c 3"
command | getline terminalCountry
close(command)
```

But it feels a bit like overkill here, you might just be interested in:

```
terminalCountry=substr($6,length($6)-3)
```

Interesting reads:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Close-Files-And-Pipes

Comment: A failsafe version in the [answer of EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54653030/8344060)

Comment: What if $6 is empty

Comment: @MuddassirRahman if `$6` has a length smaller then 3, it will return the original string. So if `$6` is empty, you will get an empty string back.

Answer (score 2):

If this:

```
"echo -n "$6" | tail -c 3" | getline terminalCountry
```

were a reasonable thing to do then the syntax for doing it would be:

```
cmd = "echo -n \047" $6 "\047 | tail -c 3"
terminalCountry = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "IND" )
close(cmd)
```

but it's not a reasonable thing to do. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for everything you need to know about using `getline`.

In this case you appear to be just trying to get the last 3 chars from `$6` and that'd just be:

```
terminalCountry = substr($6,length($6)-3)
```

Comment: This is almost identical. You were just a few seconds earlier. ;-)

Comment: actually I din't understand of doing substring again , when you already took in this line   terminalCountry = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "IND" )

Comment: @MuddassirRahman EdMorton implied that you could replace the entire getline part with just this single line.

Comment: @MuddassirRahman  if $6 has a length smaller then 3, it will return the original string. So if $6 is empty, you will get an empty string back.